# jquery ajax response not loaded into page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm following http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery--net-10225 . I have a series of buttons on my page . When I click

```
     <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-action="CNN" data-toggle="tab">CNN</a>
```

it activates:

```
      case "CNN":

                requestCrossDomain('http://www.cnn.com', function(results) {
                    $('#cnn').html(results);
                 });javasc
```

I have:

```
<div id="cnn">

    </div>
```

in my markup. When I click the button I can see the ajax request returning a response but nothing appears on my page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged to see what is in the results object?

Comment: It looks like their code uses data.results which would be results.results in your case.